# replace tokens in resource and webapp files

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I would like to improve the way our gradle build replaces `@VERSION@` with `project.version` in some of our resource and webapp files.

I currently (groovy) have:

```
def replaceVersionInResources(pattern) {
    processResources {
        filesMatching(pattern) {
            it.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['VERSION': project.version])
        }
    }
}
```

which is imported in our build.gradle files and then called with:

```
replaceVersionInResources('**/*.conf')
```

Note that the `project.version` must be set before calling `replaceVersionInResources`.

The improved version should **retrieve the file-pattern from an extension property and allow the
`project.version` to be set at a later point**.

I was able to achieve this for Java source code and am looking for a similar solution for resources and webapp files.

---

The current webapp code is very similar (obviously with the same downsides):

```
def replaceVersionInWebapp(matchingPattern) {
    if (project.tasks.findByName('bootWar')) {
        bootWar {
            filesMatching(matchingPattern) {
                it.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['VERSION': project.version])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is our solution for Java Source Code.
**Feedback is welcome!**

I created a `Sync` task, which used the main `SourceSet` as input:
`from(project.the<SourceSetContainer>()[SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME].java)`
and then afterwards wired the output of this task as input to the `CompileJava` tasks:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    setSource(replaceVersionInSource.get().outputs)
}
```

Everything below is from one file (`buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/versioning.gradle.kts`):

```kotlin
// Based on https://discuss.gradle.org/t/indirection-lazy-evaluation-for-copy-spec-filter-properties/7173/7
class DeferredReplaceTokens(`in`: Reader) : FilterReader(`in`) {
    private var actualReader: FilterReader? = null
    var tokens: MapProperty<String, String>? = null
    private fun reader(): FilterReader {
        actualReader = actualReader ?: ReplaceTokens(this.`in`).also { replaceTokens ->
            val tokens = this.tokens
            if (tokens == null) {
                println("No tokens set.  tokens is null")
            } else {
                tokens.keySet().get()
                    .map { key -> key to tokens.getting(key).get() }
                    .onEach { println("Token: ${it.first} : ${it.second}") }
                    .map { (key, value) -> ReplaceTokens.Token().also { it.key = key; it.value = value } }
                    .forEach(replaceTokens::addConfiguredToken)
            }
        }
        return actualReader!!
    }
    override fun read(cbuf: CharArray, off: Int, len: Int): Int = reader().read(cbuf, off, len)
    override fun read(): Int = reader().read()
    override fun close() = reader().close()
}
```

Here is the extension I've created, with the tokens-map and the `resourcePattern`.

```kotlin
open class ReplaceVersionExtension @Inject constructor(
    project: Project
) {
    val tokens: MapProperty<String, String> = project.objects.mapProperty(String::class.java, String::class.java)
        .convention(project.provider { mutableMapOf("VERSION" to "${project.version}") })
    val resourcePattern: Property<String> = project.objects.property(String::class.java)
    val webappPattern: Property<String> = project.objects.property(String::class.java)
}
```

```kotlin
val replaceVersion = extensions.create<ReplaceVersionExtension>("replaceVersion")

val replaceVersionInSource by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
    onlyIf { replaceVersion.tokens.get().isNotEmpty() }

    from(project.the<SourceSetContainer>()[SourceSet.MAIN_SOURCE_SET_NAME].java)
    inputs.property("tokens", replaceVersion.tokens)

    filter<DeferredReplaceTokens>("tokens" to replaceVersion.tokens)

    into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("src"))
}
```

Here is the part where I tell the `JavaCompile` tasks to use the output from the `Sync` task above.

```kotlin
tasks.withType<JavaCompile>().configureEach {
    setSource(replaceVersionInSource.get().outputs)
}
```

This code is then imported and if necessary configured using the extension:

```kotlin
replaceVersion {
    tokens.put("VERSION", "CUSTOM_VERSION_TEXT")
    tokens.put("RELEASE", "2021")
}
```